# Error trying to run Scala Application inside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

I'm using Eclipse Scala plugin. I created a simple program:

```
object HelloWorld {
  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World!")
  }
}
```

I can run this program from the menu: Run As -> Scala Application

However, with this code

```
object HelloWorld extends Application {
  println("Hello world!")
}
```

I get this error message: "Selection does not contain a main type"

Does anyboby know how to solve this?

Comment: in NetBeans you get such error when SCALA_HOME environment variable is not set

Comment: This question is not about NetBeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000176-object-extending-application-trait-not-executable). In a version of scala plugin for eclipse that I use this bug is repeatable only for objects in default package.

By the way, the usage of Application trait is not recommended - see [corresponding documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Application.html) for details.

Comment: My object is in package com.example

Comment: +1 WAS a known bug. It's fixed in the latest versions http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000094-extends-application. And in fact the Helios version is not yet supported.

Comment: As of Scala 2.9, the `Application` trait will migrate from being "not recommended" to being "advocated".  The problems with it have been resolved and, after all, it is so much cleaner to write...